# MySQL - Selecting the same column resulting in 2 different output

Tags: mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I have table that looks like this:

```
item_id | item_name
--------+-------------
123     | Blue_Ocean
234     | Green_Grass
```

I would like to query the columns from that table, so that the result would be like so,

```
item_id | item_name   | item_name_without_underscore
--------+-------------+------------------------------
123     | Blue_Ocean  | Blue Ocean
234     | Green_Grass | Green Grass
```

Is this possible with just a query? Or do I have to parse the result that I want in the backend side of my app?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `replace()`:

```
select item_id, item_name,
       replace(item_name, '_', ' ') as item_name_without_underscore
from t;
```